# I'd like to know the meaning of cv error

Tags: android, c++, opencv

I'm using QCAR in android, and trying to convert QCARImage to cvMat and change color with cvtColor.

I got the following error in cvtColor, and I'd like to know the meaning of this error.
What does each of (dcn == 3 || dcn == 4), scn == 2 and depth == CV_8U mean?

09-23 14:12:54.944: E/cv::error()(23942): OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((dcn == 3 || dcn == 4) && scn == 2 && depth == CV_8U) in void cv::cvtColor(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, int, int), file /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 3389
09-23 14:12:54.944: A/libc(23942): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 23963 (Thread-884)

Here is my code

```
QCAR::State state = QCAR::Renderer::getInstance().begin();

// Explicitly render the Video Background
QCAR::Renderer::getInstance().drawVideoBackground();

//get the captured frame of camera
QCAR::Image *img = NULL;
QCAR::Frame frame = state.getFrame();
//getting qcar::image data from QCAR
for (int i = 0; i < frame.getNumImages(); ++i) {
    const QCAR::Image *QCARimage = frame.getImage(i);
    LOGD("format %d", QCARimage->getFormat());
    if (QCARimage->getFormat() == QCAR::RGB565) {
        img = (QCAR::Image*) QCARimage;
        break;
    }
}

if(img){
    //converting to mat
    Mat capture = Mat(img->getHeight(), img->getWidth(), CV_8UC3, (unsigned char *)img->getPixels());

cvtColor(capture, capture, CV_BGR5652BGR, 0);
}
```

Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 4):

The assert message is pretty much cryptic, here's the interpretation:

`scn` and `dcn` are the numbers of channels in the source and destination images, respectively. And `depth`, well, is the the depth of source and destination images.

So, in English, it means that your input image must have the CV_8UC2 type (since 5+6+5=16 bits=2 bytes) and your destination image must have either the CV_8UC3 or CV_8UC4 type.

Also, you cannot make the conversion in-place, so the (hopefully) correct code should look something like this:

```
Mat capture = Mat(img->getHeight(), img->getWidth(), CV_8UC2, (unsigned char *)img->getPixels());
Mat converted = Mat(img->getHeight(), img->getWidth(), CV_8UC3);
cvtColor(capture, converted, CV_BGR5652BGR, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I've been stuck in this problem for a half of day, but now completely resolved.